# I got an error when I tried adding a login to my account

Tags: bug, openid, login

I have a gmail and a google email (@google.com). And I want to be able to login to Stackoverflow using either of them.

I authenticated with my gmail account. I tried add more logins using my own openID URL
https://google.com/accounts/o8/site-xrds?hd=google.com. It will redirect to Google's internal authentication page. But after the standard authorization page, I see an error reads:

> Unable to log in with your OpenID provider: 
>   Error occurred while sending a direct message or getting the response.

I can live with only logging in with my gmail account. But it would be really nice if I can use either of them to authenticate.

Comment: It's been a day since this happened.  Have you tried adding the login again?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I still have the same error. It appears more a bug than lack of feature to me.